# How will I check if one web app can access any resource within the VNet on azure web service?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, kudu

I have one web app integrated with a sub-net under one Vnet (Virtual network).
Now, I want to know whether this web app has access to other resources (other web app, DB, etc. in the same VNet) which are integrated with same sub-net under same Vnet using kudu console.

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, Open your web app and navigate to Kudu console and then just open a cmd prompt and ping away whatever the DB or AppServer etc

Comment: thanks @Sajeetharan ..i got this.. so to check the access i should tcping (i am using linux os) to private IP to the web app,  can you tell me how will i find the private ip of those web app integrated with subnet under same Vnet

Comment: It should be available on the appservice overview itself, and also you need to definite the security rules https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview#default-security-rules